# Python 3: lists and dictionary. How can I create a dictionary that tells me what list each item is from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

given these two lists:

```
lst_1=['Apple', 'pie', 'is', 'the', 'most', 'delicious'] #list 1
lst_2=['It', 'is', 'Americas', 'best'] #list 2
```

how can place them in a dictionary, for it to tell me which list (1 or 2) it is from, like this:

```
d['Apple'] = [1] #"Apple "is in list 1
d['pie']=[1]     #"pie" is in list 1
d['is']=[1,2] #"is" is in list 1 and 2
d['It']=[2]   # "It" is in list 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst_1=['Apple', 'pie', 'is', 'the', 'most', 'delicious'] #list 1
lst_2=['It', 'is', 'Americas', 'best'] #list 2

d = {}

for val in lst_1:
    d[val] = [1]

for val in lst_2:
    if val not in d:
        d[val] = [2]
    else:
        d[val] = [1,2]


print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst_1=['Apple', 'pie', 'is', 'the', 'most', 'delicious'] #list 1
lst_2=['It', 'is', 'Americas', 'best'] #list 2

d = {}
for index, i in enumerate([lst_1, lst_2]):
    for j in i:
        d.setdefault(j, set([]))
        d[j].add(index+1)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections  import defaultdict
lst_1=['Apple', 'pie', 'is', 'the', 'most', 'delicious'] #list 1
lst_2=['It', 'is', 'Americas', 'best'] #list 2
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in lst_1:
    d[i].append(1)
for i in lst_2:
    d[i].append(2)
```

`dict(d)` gives

```
{'Apple': [1], 'pie': [1], 'is': [1, 2], 'the': [1], 'most': [1], 'delicious': [1], 'It': [2], 'Americas': [2], 'best': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
myDictionary= {
  "list1" : {
    "1" : "Apple",
    "2" : "pie",
    "3" : "is",
    "4" : "most",
    "5" : "delicious."
  },
  "list2" : {
    "1" : "It",
    "2" : "is",
    "3" : "America's",
    "4" : "best,"
  }
}
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehensions to form `dict` object:

```
d={i : [1] for i in lst_1}
d.update({i: d.get(i, []) + [2] for i in lst_2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
lst_1=['Apple', 'pie', 'is', 'the', 'most', 'delicious']
lst_2=['It', 'is', 'Americas', 'best']

dic={}
joined_list= lst_1 + lst_2
for e in joined_list:
    if e in lst_1 and e in lst_2:
        dic[e] = [1, 2]
    elif e in lst_1:
        dic[e] = [1]
    elif e in lst_2:
        dic[e] = [2]
print(dic)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
d= {}
lst = set(lst_1 + lst_2)
for i in lst:
    if i in lst_1 and i in lst_2:
        d[i] = [1,2]
    elif i in lst_2:
        d[i] = [2]
    elif i in lst_1:
        d[i] = [1]
print(d)
```

Comment: @Lulabelle95 Check this out